# edit the last inserted record in mongodb

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I am inserting two different objects into the db, i am doing this according to a certain criteria.

After that i am editing this record and setting the status to verified or not verified according to an amazon reply.

The problem is , i want to update the record that has been just inserted , since i am using findOneAndUpdate, only one record is being edited and it is not the last one it is the first.

Since the user can do as many purchases as he wants , he can have as many records as he want but only the first object found in the db having the userId sent as a param is edited.

what shall i use? the date and time when the object is inserted or what ?

```
async createAndSendToAmazon(data) {
    try {
      const records = new this.model(data);
      const purchaseFromAppObjectRecord = await records.save();
      let userId = purchaseFromAppObjectRecord.UserData[0].userId;
      let receiptId = purchaseFromAppObjectRecord.receiptId;
      await sendToAmazon(userId, receiptId);
      await changeStatusToVerified(userId);
      return purchaseFromAppObjectRecord;
    } catch (error) {
      return error;
    }
  }
}
```

```
async function sendToAmazon(userId, receiptId) {
  const requestUrl = `https://appstore-sdk.amazon.com/version/1.0/verifyReceiptId/developer/2:smXBjZkWCxDMSBvQ8HBGsUS1PK3jvVc8tuTjLNfPHfYAga6WaDzXJPoWpfemXaHg:iEzHzPjJ-XwRdZ4b4e7Hxw==/user/${userId}/receiptId/${receiptId}`;
  console.log(requestUrl);

  fetch(requestUrl).then(function (response) {
    if (response.status === 200) {
      console.log(response.status);
      response.json().then(async function (data) {
        AmazonResolver.create(data);
      });
    } else {
      try {
        changeStatusToNotVerified(userId);
        console.log(response.status);
        response.json();
        console.log("err will not add amazon verification object");
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```
async function changeStatusToVerified(userId) {
  try {
    await purchaseFromAppObjectModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        UserData: { $elemMatch: { userId: userId } },
      },
      { $set: { status: "verified" } }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

I want to write down my question as a minimal one but i want you to see my functions.

Answer (score 0):

// you can use sort aggregate function to sort users in desc order and update the last element first

```
async function changeStatusToVerified(userId) {
  try {
    await purchaseFromAppObjectModel.findOneAndUpdate(
      {
        UserData: { $elemMatch: { userId: userId } },
      },
      { $set: { status: "verified" } },
      { sort: { userId: -1 }, upsert: true, returnNewDocument: true }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
                  OR 


  async function changeStatusToVerified(userId) {
      try {
        await purchaseFromAppObjectModel.findOneAndUpdate(
          {
            UserData: { $elemMatch: { userId: userId } },
          },
          { $set: { status: "verified" } },
          { sort: { userId: -1 } }
        );
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

if any one passes by here later on , this worked for me :

```
.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          UserData: { $elemMatch: { userId: userId } },
        },
        { $set: { status: "verified" }, limit: 1 }
      )
      .sort({ $natural: -1 });
```